# how to replace character in a string variable using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

In my serverless.yml script which uses CloudFormation syntax I have defined a name for my app using the `appName` variable:

```
custom:
  appName: my-app-name
```

Somewhere down the script I use this `appName` variable to assemble the url path string, such as:

```
  myEndpoint:
    events:
      - http:
          path: /${{self:custom.appName}}/index
```

which will result to a `path` being `/my-app-name/index`

But I would like to replace the `-` characters with `_` dashes.

What would be the cleanest way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with plain CloudFormation. You have to use [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), though a custom resource could also be used. Specifically, you can use `Replace` macro developed my AWS and available at [aws-cloudformation /
aws-cloudformation-macros](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-macros/tree/master/StringFunctions). You can also develop your own macros, or modified the one given by AWS as it is open sourced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split and join functions. First, Fn::split your string using the original character, which is "-" in your case, and then Fn::Join back all values from the list returned by Fn::Split with the desired character "_".

```
{"Fn::Join": ["_", { "Fn::Split" : ["-", {"Ref": "myVar"}]}]}
```

Comment: Late, but i want share my finding for people which hit that question like me today ;-)